# How can we use a javascript variable in Fitnesse?

Tags: fitnesse

I am trying to pass a value from a function of JavaScript to Fitnesse page. I have defined a variable in Fitnesse page using syntax " !define  {default_value} ". But I want to assign the value to this variable from Java script.  Is there any way we can pass the value from javascript to fitnesse variable??

Comment: How would this work in CI?  Can you explain why you need to do this?

Comment: I had created a drop down menu to select dynamically from fitnesse web page. I need to set the selected value from drop down list to a variable defined in fitnesse page so that I can use the selected value in our test case. I created a javascript which runs on the "onChange" event of drop down list and store the selected value in a variable. Now I need to pass the value of selected item from javascript function to the variabledefined in fitnesse.

Answer (score 0):

This has come up recently from another FitNesse user.    As I understand FitNesse, this won't work.  The way that FitNesse runs the test page, it doesn't actually use the page that you see when it runs the test.  When you click on the test button, the following happens:

1. The TestResponder gets the page that you want to run
2. The TestResponder fetches the page that is to be run from the wiki
3. The test is executed

When you click on the Test button, it is the same as if you had typed in the following URL in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/FrontPage.MyTest?test
```

As such, FitNesse doesn't know anything about the state of the page in the browser.

There has been a recent proposal of allowing the passing of properties as a part of the URL that could then be rendered by a ${property} variable reference.

Additionally, there are other considerations for how this would work.  One of the issues is when you run a test as a part of a suite, how would you set your drop down.

The best way to do this is probably to make sure you have either test pages for each option in that drop-down.  I recommend this because presumably they produce different results, or why would they matter?

The other way to do this would be to create a scenario for what you want to test and then call that scenario with each value.

Ultimately, the thing you want to do isn't something that FitNesse is good at.